# How erase Paint with the finger

Tags: android

I want to erase by area where the finger is detected on the gray square bitmap but it don't works.

I display a bitmap with ic_launch as image then i display on the image a grey square Paint where i can to modify the color to the TRANSPARENT

What is the problem? Thank you

```
private Bitmap mBitmap;
private Canvas mCanvas;
private Path mPath;
private Paint mBitmapPaint;
private Paint mPaint;

public CaseView(Context c) {
    super(c);

    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(40);


    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
            mBitmap.setPixel(i, j, Color.GRAY);
        }

    }
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    mPath = new Path();
    mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(0, 0, oldw, oldh);

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawRect(100, 100, 200, 200, mBitmapPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

    Bitmap _scratch = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

    // logo
    canvas.drawBitmap(_scratch, 0, 100, null);



    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
            if ((mX < 100 && mX >= 0) && (mY < 100 && mY >= 0)) {

                mBitmap.setPixel((int) mY,(int) mX,  Color.TRANSPARENT);
            }
        }

    }
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 100, mBitmapPaint);

    Bitmap mutableBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(_scratch.getWidth(),
            _scratch.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mutableBitmap.setPixel(50, 50, 124);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mutableBitmap, 0, 100, null);
    int pixelColor = mBitmap.getPixel(50, 50);
    int red = Color.red(pixelColor);
    int green = Color.green(pixelColor);
    Log.v("red", "red:" + red + " /green:" + green);


}


private float mX, mY;
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}

private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
}

private void touch_up() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    // commit the path to our offscreen
    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    // kill this so we don't double draw
    mPath.reset();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();
    Log.v("onTouchEvent", "x:" + x + "/y:" + y);

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        touch_start(x, y);
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        touch_move(x, y);
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        touch_up();
        invalidate();
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Did you check it? Let me know if you solved it..If yes then mark it as answer

Answer (score 5):

For Drawing you need to draw a path using one Paint class. But for erasing again you have to draw one path on your touch Coordinate like this

```
mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
```

In **android-sdk** sample they had given a class **FingerPaint** that explain it very well

Comment: @user1881979 But i have some issue on using mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)); Can u look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229496/eraser-with-porterduff-mode-clear-always-draws-a-transparent-line