# Android Use finger to erase bitmap transparency and match background

Tags: android, canvas, transparency

**Scenario:**

1. Use `FingerPaint` example as a basis
2. Draw some text into the `FingerPaint` region
3. Want user to be able to erase some part of the text with the finger by dragging over it

*Reference: 
[How erase Paint with the finger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13742297/how-erase-paint-with-the-finger)*

**Tries:**

It almost gets where I want, but with `SRC` and with `CLEAR` the dragging path is black. I would prefer the dragging path to be the color drawn to the canvas without redrawing the entire canvas as the finger moves.

If you know FingerPaint they do this:

```
canvas.drawColor(0xFFAAAAAA);
```

I wrote some black colored text on top of this canvas via drawText.
Then I tried the following combos to allow the user to erase the text:

```
mPaint.setColor(0xFFAAAAAA);
mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));

mPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));

mPaint.setColor(0x00AAAAAA);
mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
```

You can multiply those three out by substituting the `CLEAR` mode with `SRC` mode and showed same result.

**Question:**

Anyone know how I can make my erasure `drawPath` take the appropriate action of erasing the part of the bitmap it is dragged over and while it is doing that the path that is being dragged should match the color drawn to the canvas underneath the text?